# Cryptojs encryption with Pkcs padding in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cryptojs

I am trying to create an encrypted request at the frontend using cryptojs using below code:

```
  function createAesRequestPayload(jsonRequiredToEncrypt) {
  var base64Key =  $window.CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
  var ivkey =  $window.CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/16);

  var aesEncrypted = $window.CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(jsonRequiredToEncrypt), base64Key,
    { iv: ivkey, mode: $window.CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: $window.CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});

  var iv = btoa(ivkey);
  var key = btoa(base64Key);
  var data = btoa(aesEncrypted.toString());
  var ivAndKey = iv + "|" + key;
  var header = crypt.encrypt(ivAndKey); // Using RSA
  return (header + "|" + data);
}
```

Via this code, I am able to create request but on the server-side, I am getting an exception:

```
Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

Backend is working fine for android and IOS, and I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

The padding used at the backend

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding")
```

I don't have the backend with me only I can see the logs on the server.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are vastly different languages. PLease don’t apply the java tag to a JavaScript question (nor the other way around).